# "'int' object is not callable" error

Tags: python

Here is my script, http://pastebin.com/zgRrBX0U

For the reference this is a script for ex36 of Zed Shaw's 'Learning python the hard way'.
I was attempting to create a text based adventure designed from the first level of Legend of Zelda.

But I ran into a problem, as I start into the program. It works so that you will start in the main room. But no matter which direction one goes it will have an error saying. " 'int' object is not callable.' I could not figure out what this meant by searching. Or looking at the pydocs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please put the relevant code into the body of your question.

Comment: You might also want to spend some time overhauling your design.  Hardcoding each "colorful description" of each room, movement, and enemy is not allowing for good code-reuse, will make your code a living hell to maintain, and is also hard to read.

Comment: Python isn't the first programming language you've used, is it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel , Well it kinda is. I used to do c, but I gave up after two years of failing. So I hope python will be the first language I can actually say I program in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 47:

```
def roomBA(key, life, door_open, roomBA, roomDA):
```

Your are defining a function named roomBA here.

line 129:

```
roomBA = 0
```

Here, you have changed roomBA to be the number 0 now.

Therefore, the original function you defined is lost.  You no longer have a name to use to call it anymore.

On line 132:

```
roomCA(key, life, door_open, roomBA, roomDA)
```

Here, you are calling the function roomCA.  Among other things, this function asks for a direction from the player, and then attempts to call the corresponding room function.

I typed, west, so we tried to call the function referenced by the variable roomBA (line 17).  But, oh noes, its no longer a function.  It's 0.  Hence, you're error.

What's going on is that you have a lot of collisions between function names, and variable names.  Of course, roomXX are functions that represent each room in your game.  Then, you have state variables (which, for now, are also named roomXX).  It appears these variables are intended to track whether you've entered a room before.  Since both your functions and state variables are named the same things, you're doing all sorts of unexpected things.

As the post above mentioned, you can delete line 129 and 130 to get the code to run; but, you probably need to get a better understanding of the basics.  Here's a place to start:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score 2):

You define `roomBA` and `roomDA` as functions, and then later on... you bind them to integers. Of course it's not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

Delete lines 129 and 130 and it will work, as Ignacio says.

In Python a "callable" is usually a function. The message means you are treating a number (an "int") as if it were a function (a "callable"), so Python doesn't know what to do, so it stops.

Comment: I have now fixed the problem, very silly of me. It works fine and I can move on with this little project, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> an error saying. " 'int' object is not callable.' I could not figure out what this meant by searching.

You're meant to figure out what this means by knowing the basics of the language as well as English.

The error says that an `'int'` object is not callable. Calling is what you do to functions (and similar things), so you have an int where you thought you had a function (or something similar). This is because you've rebound a function name to an int.

In Python, as you should be aware by now:

1. Everything is an object, even functions.
2. Types are not checked until run-time.
3. Values have type, not variables (names, really).

So there is nothing preventing you from writing:

```
function a(): pass
a = 1
```

The first line creates a function object, and binds it to the name `a`. The second line binds the integer `1` to the name `a`. This replaces the old binding, so `a` is *no longer a name for the function*.